# How can I get timestamp for selected date range in Java

Tags: java, pojo

```
public class DateTime {
    public static java.util.LinkedList searchBetweenDates(java.util.Date startDate, java.util.Date endDate) 
    {
       java.util.Date begin = new Date(startDate.getTime());
        java.util.LinkedList list = new java.util.LinkedList();
        list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));

        while(begin.compareTo(endDate)<0)
        {
            begin = new Date(begin.getTime() + 86400000);
            list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));

            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
            int total=3;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            for(int d=0; d<=total; d++)
            {
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
            timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());

            }
            System.out.println(timestamp);  
        }
        return list;

    }

  public static void main( String[] args )throws Exception
  {
      java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the Start Date: dd/mm/yyyy");
      String begin = new String();
      begin = input.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter the End Date: dd/mm/yyyy");
      String end = new String();
      end = input.nextLine();

      java.util.LinkedList hitList = searchBetweenDates(
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(begin),
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(end));

      String[] comboDates = new String[hitList.size()];
      for(int i=0; i<hitList.size(); i++)
          comboDates[i] = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy ").format(((java.util.Date)hitList.get(i)));

      for(int i=0; i<comboDates.length; i++)
          System.out.println(comboDates[i]);


      input.close();
    }
  }
```

I want to print time-stamp for selected date range not for current date. For
example, if I have selected date range **from 01/01/2016 to 05/01/2016** then the output should be like this:

```
         01/01/2016 12:02:01
                    12:04:45
                    till
                    11:59:00


          02/01/2016 12:02:01
                     12:04:45
```

same for all till end date. But by this code I am getting current date and current time-stamp and after the selected date range's only date not time-stamp.

Comment: If anybody knows the solution please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get the current date because `Calendar.getInstance()` returns a `Calendar` object set to current date. So after that line, you need to set the time to the beginning date using `cal.setTime(begin)`.

Also,printing the time stamp has to be done within your for-loop, otherwise only the last time stamp of that day will be printed.

I assume you also want both the start date and the end date to be printed as time stamps. To do so, you have to move the line `begin = new Date(begin.getTime() + 86400000)` to the end of the while loop, otherwise you will skip the start date. By doing so, you will probably see that the end date will not be printed. Therefore, you also have set the time of the end date to the end of the day before the while-loop.

**Edit:** To set the time of the end date to end of the day, so it's also displayed, try using `endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime() + 24*3600*1000)`. This way, the date will be shifted by one day in the future and the whole endDate will also be used. Remember to do this BEFORE the while loop.

Comment: i have added time for end date too but its not giving me end date ...either it is working. suggest something different or explore that

Comment: See my edit for information on how to do what I mean.

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, please remember to accept it.